# Get duration audio take 8 - 10 seconds, What's the best way to get it?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a loop where there's a filter to mp3 files, but when I want get duration of files took 8 - 10 seconds, I tried with Mediaplayer.create,get.Duration,MediaMetadaretrieve and Mediaplayer.setDatasource.get.Duration, but they took 8 - 10 seconds except Mediaplayer.setDatasource that will be crash it,

```
File scan;
File[]list;
String song_path;
int posicion;
int minutes;
int seconds;
ArrayList<String>Song_list=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    metada=new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    scan= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    list=scan.listFiles();

    for(File files:list){
        if(files.getName().endsWith("mp3")){
            song_path=String.valueOf(files.getAbsolutePath());
            Song_list.add(song_path);

            metada.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,Uri.parse(song_path));
            String dutation=metada.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
            posicion=Integer.parseInt(dutation)/1000;
            minutes=posicion/60;
            seconds=posicion%60;
            text.setText(minutes+":"+seconds+text.getText());

            /*player=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,Uri.parse(song_path));
            posicion=player.getDuration()/1000;
            minutes=posicion/60;
            seconds=posicion/60;
            text.setText(minutes+":"+seconds+text.getText());*/
        }
    }

}
```

}

I know that the codes  Media.create and metada.extracMetada are they who took a lot of time, Thank you for the attention

Comment: Query the `MediaStore` instead of doing all this yourself.

Comment: Could give me a example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26619688/115145  http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/android-audio-cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AudioFileIO Java class to read and retreive files data

Example in your For loop you can use this Instead :

```
    AudioFile myMp3 = AudioFileIO.read(files);
   duration = myMp3.getAudioHeader().getTrackLength();
```

Comment: How to import AudioFileIO in android studio

Comment: First Download JAudioTagger Library and then add the library to your project ,import it and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use ExoPlayer which is also by Android and takes much lesser time in getting the duration of an audio mp3 file.  It is better in implementation and plays files from url as well as local files. Plus you can customise it also for any view and has all kinds of listeners.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: I will look into it